# I'm having a weird issue with bed leveling (Z-Axis) ?? Ender 3 V2

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis

I'm having a weird issue with bed leveling (Z-Axis) ?? Ender 3 V2

Every time I try to level it when I go to the bottom left corner and so on and come back to that corner the Z-axis drops about .1 mm each go around. It used to drop more than that, this is the lowest I've got it to drop by and can't stop it.

Still nothing, I squared everything off with a T-square and tightened everything precisely.

I watched these and did one by one:

I did what this site recommended which was part of the first video:

https://3dsolved.com/ender-3-x-axis-sagging-how-to-solve/

Mind you I've checked numerous sites and videos and these explained everything properly and were the most up-to-date.

I ordered another Z-axis making it a dual and seeing if that will fix the problem.

Comment: Do you still have stock bed springs and knobs?

Comment: No I've switched them out a while ago. I have new gold springs, about a week old. The weird thing is I've started printing again and everything prints normally. Only in bed leveling the z axis sags

Comment: SOLVED just add another z axis, printed a spacer for the bottom of the z motors at 1.4mm and leveled both sides with corner levels(post pipe levels) from lowes. Add a washer to the nuts towards the back side inside of the new z axis lead screw bracket and done. No more sag https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08RJDW5W6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

The extra Z-axis did help but it was all the eccentric nuts. Make sure you can move them with little force, not you trying to open a bottle of soda but a little lighter than that

I solved the issue by just adding another Z-axis, I also printed a spacer for the bottom of the Z motors at 1.4 mm and leveled both sides with corner levels (post pipe levels) from Lowes. Add a washer to the nuts towards the backside inside of the new Z-axis lead screw bracket and done. No more sag.

[Creality Ender 3 Accessories Dual Z-Axis Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08RJDW5W6)